# Kotlin Assigment operator Overloading and Type conversion

Tags: types, kotlin, overloading, operator-keyword

How to overload an assignment operator to convert between two different classes?

```
class A
class B

val bb: B = B();
val aa: A = bb;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin only supports overloading of some predefined operators. See this documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading).

What you're trying there is not possible, you cannot assign some `B` to a variable of type `A` unless their type hierarchy allows it as shown here:

```
open class A
class B : A()

val bb: B = B()
val aa: A = bb
```